# c++ boost conditional remove from container

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

i want to do something like c# linq style :

```
SomeColection <SomeType> someColection;
someColection.Remove(something => something > 2);
```

and it'll remove all the things that are bigger then 2 (or any other boolean condition)...

using boost in the project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need a simple template wrapper:

```
template <class Container, class UnaryPredicate>
void erase_if(Container& container, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  container.erase(
    std::remove_if(container.begin(), container.end(), pred),
    container.end()
  );
}
```

It's a well-known idiom, however it won't be possible with `map` or `set` as they maintain their own order.

Then, you can use [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda.html) to get the syntax you wish for writing the predicate itself.

```
using boost::lambda::_1;

SomeCollection<Type> someCollection;

erase_if(someCollection, _1 > 2);
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need boost (unless your main focus is that inline anonymous function). [Plain STL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_if) is fine.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
        std::vector<int> x (24);
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++ i)
                x[i] = i % 5;

        std::vector<int>::iterator
          new_end = std::remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(),
                                   std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), 2));
        x.erase(new_end, x.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++ i)
                std::cout << x[i] << " ";

        return 0;
}
```

---

With boost you can replace the bind2nd stuff with

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

...

    using boost::lambda::_1;
    std::vector<int>::iterator new_end = std::remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), _1 > 2);
```

Comment: +1. I would just replace the output line with an `std::copy( x.begin(), x.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );` to hide the loop away... but that is just a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 5):

C++0x (using lambdas):

```
container.erase( std::remove_if( container.begin(), container.end(), 
                                 []( int v ) { return v > 2; } ),
                 container.end() );
```

The reason for the `erase` combined with the `remove_if` is that STL algorithms apply to iterators, and not containers. They relocate the contents of the container, but they do not modify the container per-se.

C++03:

```
container.erase( std::remove_if( container.begin(), container.end(), 
                                 std::bind2nd( std::greater<int>(), 2 ) ),
                 container.end() );
```

This may seem a little simpler, but it is also less flexible, as there are only so many predicates already defined. For more complex operations you would have to write your own predicate functor.

Comment: can i do that in MS visual studio?

Comment: @Hellfrost: If you are using VS2010 you can.

Comment: VS 2008 still... but hopefully in the next couple of weeks we'll get 2010

Answer (score 1):

By the way, boost::range v.1.46.0 (released in 2011) has exactly what you want - the **remove_erase_if** algorithm

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/erase.hpp

std::vector<int> vec = {1, 6, 2, 7};
boost::range::remove_erase_if(vec, [](int val){return val > 5;});
```

Short and straightforward.